# How can I convert an Userform Textbox value which is a String into a Long in Excel Vba?

Tags: vba, excel

Here I am trying to read a `Textbox.Value` which is a `String` into a `Variable` (i.e. `text_bval`) and converting that `String` into a `Long` using `CLng` function for my calculations. The `CLng` function is showing run time error like type mismatch.

See my code below:

```
Dim text_bval As String  
Dim text_long As Long  
Dim per As Integer  
text_bval = text_box.value  
user_entry = CLng(text_bval)
```

Comment: Please show example data as well. Type mismatch indicates that you might be getting unexpected (or unintended) data in your variable.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [MS Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ck4c5842(v=vs.84).aspx), "If `expression` lies outside the acceptable range for the Long subtype, an error occurs."

In this case, your expression is `text_bval`, a string. If your string contains characters that cannot be converted to a number, an error will occur.

For example:

`text_bval = "2"` then `CLng(text_bval) = 2`

`text_bval = "2.3"` then `CLng(text_bval) = 2`

`text_bval = "hello"` then `CLng(text_bval) = ERROR`

In order to prevent an error from occuring, you should do something like the following:

```
user_entry = 0
On Error Resume Next
user_entry = CLng(text_bval)
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: I think there is a `Exit Function` or something like this missing. Because if it success, it will still execute the `On Error GoTo 0`. Am I right? Correct me please if not.

Comment: `On Error GoTo 0` is the normal state of error trapping. You do not want to stay in the `On Error Resume Next` state any longer than you need to.

Comment: would recommend isNummeric() and not on error resume next =)